# Plural and singular array names in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-chrome

I'm very confused by the behavior of this code in Chrome 59.0.3071.115:

```
var names = ["Cat 1", "Cat 2"];
console.log(names);
```

Prints an array object, but

```
var name = ["Cat 1", "Cat 2"];
console.log(name);
```

Prints the string `"Cat 1, Cat 2"`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` is a predefined [getter/setter property of the `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name), and will always be a string data type. So when you assign to it, you are not assigning to a variable, but using a setter, which will convert the given value to a string.